# Como recuperar parâmetros passado pelo método use(), dentro de uma função?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou estudando `callbacks` e deparei com um método que não consigo recuperar e acho até mais simples de enviar as variáveis para dentro da função que é o operador use, mas não sei como pega-la dentro desta função my_function().

Até aqui consegui entender, o primeiro é o `callback` da `function` e o segundo é o parâmetro da my_function().

```
function my_function($call, array $foo) { 
    return $foo['ra'];
}


$bar = ['ra' => '853-5'];

$str = my_function(function($data) {
    return $data;
}, $bar);

var_dump($str); //string(5) "853-5"
```

Mas para eu puder usar desta forma!

```
$str = my_function(function($data) use ($bar) {
    return $data;
});
```

E não tendo que passar o segundo parâmetro para a função, mas sim pelo operadoe `use`. Como pego estes dados passados pelo operador `use` em my_function() ?

Desde já agradeço pela resposta!

Comment: o operador `use` é para dar a liberdade de uma variavel ser usada dentro do `callback`, e não de passa-la para a função em sí.

Comment: exatamente como o @RafaelAcioly falou, o `use` adiciona variáveis no contexto do callback, esse contexto pertence apenas ao callback e você não vai conseguir pegar-la fora desse contexto

Comment: Agora entendi, valeu e obrigado a todos!